# First commit of the particular file is not read by the git command. My script is below

Tags: git, bash, grep, commit, git-commit

1.I am trying to read all the commits of the particular file if they have added/removed keyword "compile".
2.It does not read the first commit which has these changes related to "compile"
3.What can be the issue?

```
 if grep 'compile.*' build.gradle| awk 'BEGIN {print "Dependencies" }  
                                                   { print $0 }'>>/Users/rohan/Capstone/testoutput.csv  #startifDependencies
        then 
        found=found+1
        git log --pretty=format:"%h" -- build.gradle | while read -r LINE
        do   #startDo2
            if git show $LINE build.gradle | egrep '^\-\s+compile.*' > /dev/null
                then
                lib=$(git show $LINE build.gradle | egrep '^\-\s+compile.*' | cut -d\' -f2)
                git log -1 --pretty=format:"$lib,$f,%cn,removed,%h,%ad,$found" $LINE build.gradle |  awk '{print $0}'>>/Users/rohan/Capstone/testoutput_1.csv

                elif git show $LINE build.gradle | egrep '^\+\s+compile.*' > /dev/null
                then
                lib=$(git show $LINE build.gradle | egrep '^\+\s+compile.*' | cut -d\' -f2)
                git log -1 --pretty=format:"$lib,$f,%cn,added,%h,%ad,$found" $LINE build.gradle | awk '{print $0 }'>>/Users/rohan/Capstone/testoutput_1.csv
            fi
        done  #endDo2
        else echo "Dependencies not found">>/Users/rohan/Capstone/testoutput_1.txt
        fi   #endifDependencies
        elif cd $w/$f/
```

Comment: You ought to remove the android tag. While you may be also using android, the question itself does not involve android.

Comment: `found=found+1` is weird here.

Comment: @ElpieKay Its just to maintain the count. It's not doing any manipulation here. you still think it can be a problem?

Comment: I mean `found=found+1` can't work in bash as you expect, if this is a bash script. After `found=found+1`, `echo $found` just prints "found+1". You may need `found=$(( $found + 1 ))`.

Comment: Why don't you use ` git log --regexp-ignore-case "-Scompile" --  "build.gradle"`?

Comment: I'll try that. Thank you